# How to read excel file in Synapse Notebook which is in Azure datalake gen 2 storage via abfss:// in PySpark Notebook

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I need to read the excel file which is in Gen 2 storage which need to be read in Synapse Notebook,anything is ok for me which works like using pandas too. using abfss:// path

like i M asking ,i know how go do this in databricks mounting and all.But Synapase ,Blob storage is inyegrated.So no idea on how to do . for other formats ,I am using like

`spark.read.load("abfss://file path" ,format=parquet)`.

This is working for csv and other formats ,but this will not work in databricks too,where we have to install Excel maven lib and Pandas also directly works there. But here its not working. So need a from Scratch approach to read Excel file from Blob

Comment: Have you tried any approach? Provide what you tried and error you are facing.

Comment: like i M asking ,i knkw how go do thiz in databricks mounting and all.But Synapase ,Blob stoeage is inyegrated.So no idea on how to do . for other formats ,M using like spark.read.load("abfss://file path" ,format=parquet)   .This iss working for csv and other formats ,but this will nkt work in databricks too,where we have to install Excel maven lib and Pandas alaso directly works there. But here its not working. So need a from Scratch approach to read Excel file from Blob

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below approach.

```
import pandas as pd
account_key_value="your_storage_acc_key"
df = pd.read_excel('abfs://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/xl_files/sample.xlsx', storage_options = {'account_key' : account_key_value})
s_df=spark.createDataFrame(df)
display(s_df)
```

[image]

and you can also use these storage options.

```
storage_options = {'sas_token' : 'sas_token_value'}
storage_options = {'connection_string' : 'connection_string_value'}
storage_options = {'tenant_id': 'tenant_id_value', 'client_id' : 'client_id_value', 'client_secret': 'client_secret_value'}
```

If you are using integrated storage account in synapse, then no need of giving **storage options**.

Comment: Am getting the following error if try the above piece of code :df = pd.read_excel('abfss://containerName@staccname.dfs.core.windows.net/test/file1.xlsx')

df=spark.read.load('abfss://conatinerName@staccname.dfs.core.windows.net/test/file1.parquet', format='parquet')



Error: ServiceRequestError: Cannot connect to host staccname.blob.core.windows.net:443 ssl:True [Name or service not known]

Comment: for reding the parquet file ,code dfs path is working.But for pandas its not working

Comment: you need to give path like this `abfs://container_name@storage_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_your_file`
and also try giving storage option.

Comment: For more information refer  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool) doc

Comment: i have given the same right above. I have tried acc key also ,its throwing the same error

Comment: abfs path is working if its a csv or parquet file,its not working for xlsx file

Comment: csv and parquet files are working with storage option or without it?

Comment: Yeah . Parquet and csv are fine when i give the abfs path. But issue with Excel only